# Why cart is not in sync after input change value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm developing a small fake ecommerce and I'm having trouble when I try to modify Item's quantity in the cart.
The cart state is defined at the top tree component, the Router, with all the functions that regulates it:

```js
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Products from "./Products";
import About from "./About";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Router = () => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  //add to cart function
  function addToCart(product, quantity) {
    let totPrice = parseFloat((product.price * quantity).toFixed(2));
    //get the index to check if the element is already in cart
    let existingItemIndex = cart.findIndex(
      (item) => item.title == product.title
    );
    //if it's already in cart
    if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
      //update array
      let updatedCart = [...cart];
      updatedCart[existingItemIndex].quantity = quantity;
      updatedCart[existingItemIndex].totPrice = totPrice;
      //set new Cart
      setCart(updatedCart);
    } else {
      //else add a new item in the cart
      setCart([
        ...cart,
        {
          id: product.id,
          title: product.title,
          quantity: quantity,
          totPrice: totPrice,
          img: product.image,
        },
      ]);
    }
  }

  

  function removeFromCart(cart, id) {
    setCart(cart.filter((item) => id !== item.id));
  }

  function changeQuantity(cart,id,event){
    
      let newQuantity=parseInt(event.target.value);
      let updatedCart= cart.map((item)=>item.id == id ? {...item,quantity:newQuantity}: item);
      setCart(updatedCart)
      console.log(cart)
      
  }
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <App cart={cart} removeFromCart={removeFromCart} changeQuantity={changeQuantity} />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "products",
          element: <Products addToCart={addToCart} />,
        },
        {
          path: "categories/:category",
          element: <Products addToCart={addToCart} />,
        },
        {
          path: "About",
          element: <About />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};
export default Router;
```

the function changeQuantity is passed as prop to the different child components until arrives to the Cart component

```
function Cart({cart,removeFromCart,changeQuantity}){

    return(
        <>
       <div className="cart">
            {cart.map((item)=>
       <div className="cart-item" key={item.id}>
        <div className="cart-item-info">
        <img src={item.img} alt="" />
        <div className="cart-item-description">
        <p><b>{item.title}</b></p>
        <i>Total: $ {item.totPrice}</i>
           
        </div>
       
        </div>
        <input type="number" defaultValue={item.quantity} min="1" onChange={(event)=>changeQuantity(cart,item.id,event)} />
        <button onClick={()=>removeFromCart(cart,item.id)}>Remove</button>
       </div>

       )}
       </div>
       <button className="checkOut">Checkout</button>   
       </> 
    )
}
export default Cart
```

I have 2 problems:

1. when i increment the value of the input in Cart the actual cart get updated but with a unit less (if I input 3 pieces of the same Item, in the cart there are always one less so in this case 2)
2. the total price per item in the cart doesn t get updated after changing the input value

I'm using React+Vite

Comment: why you need to pass cart state to  Cart component ? try to remove it

Comment: @AnhTuan because cart represent the array of objects added in the cart and it s used also in other part of the application. Cart is the component that actually renders the cart

Comment: i mean why you put cart in changeQuantity() and removeFromCart() ? you can handle update that in parent component